# Visual Studio showing weird taskbar previews

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

My Visual Studio taskbar previews are like this:

[image: Visual Studio Taskbar Previews]

It is showing since the last boot, as Windows was crashed last time, and the latest extension I have installed is VSCommands, but I don't think that is causing the problem.

There is no other issue, btw. Can anyone help please?

OS: Windows Technical Preview Build 10074.
VS: Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 4.

If you need any more info, let me know.

Comment: update to Build 10130 and try a newer graphic card driver.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with Windows TP as it was working before. Still, I'll try, thanks...

Comment: which GPU do you use?

Comment: AMD hasn't released official Win10 drivers :(

Comment: Yeah, I know, but my point is, that it was fine the last time my laptop was on, and it doesn't look like a driver issue, it's more like a tweak in Visual Studio.

Comment: this still looks like a GPU driver issue.

Comment: Well, maybe, but all the other apps are showing previews properly, then why only VS?

Comment: are the other applications also using WPF or the old GDI?

Comment: IDK, but there are many apps, and I believe they are using a lot of other technologies also. e.g. Android Studio (JVM), Windows Reader (WinRT), Bluestacks, Sublime Text, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 3):

VSCommands changes the VS taskbar previews to show the solution, branch and current file name. The feature is called "Solution Badges" and can be disabled from the VSCommands options page.